# a issue regarding Bridge pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I'm studing the Bridge pattern and I have a question. Regarding my code example bellow `LightSwitch` and `FanSwitch` should be the **implementor** or `Slider/RadialImplementation` is ok as implementor? My problem is to know who must be the implementor: both combinations seems to work in any order. I don't know if I'm being clear.

```
class Main
{
    static function main()
    {
        new Main();
    }

    public function new()
    {
        var s:Switch;

        s = new LightSwitch();

        s.implementation = new SliderImplementation();
        s.on();
        s.off();

        s.implementation = new DialImplementation();
        s.on();
        s.off();

        s = new FanSwitch();

        s.implementation = new SliderImplementation();
        s.on();
        s.off();

        s.implementation = new DialImplementation();
        s.on();
        s.off();
    }
}

class Switch
{
    public var implementation:SwitchImplementation;
    public function new(){}
    public function on(){}
    public function off(){}
}

class LightSwitch extends Switch 
{
    public override function on()
    {
        trace("Light");
        implementation.on();
    }
    public override function off()
    {
        implementation.off();
    }
}

class FanSwitch extends Switch 
{
    public override function on()
    {
        trace("Fan");
        implementation.on();
    }
    public override function off()
    {
        implementation.off();
    }
}

class SwitchImplementation
{
    public function new(){}
    public function on(){}
    public function off(){}
}

class SliderImplementation extends SwitchImplementation
{
    public override function on()
    {
        trace("> Slider Switch [on]");
    }
    public override function off()
    {
        trace("> Slider Switch [off]");
    }
}

class DialImp lementation extends SwitchImplementation
{
    public override function on()
    {
        trace("> Dial Switch [on]");
    }
    public override function off()
    {
        trace("> Dial Switch [off]");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *implementors* in your example are the `Slider/RadialImplementation` classes. They're hidden behind the interface exposed through the *abstraction* of the `Light/FanSwitch` classes.

Comment: yep. I wanna know if I can change this order. eg. implementors being `Light/FanSwitch` instead `Slider/Radial...` I mean, if this makes senses too.

Comment: Well, from the way you've implemented, it doesn't make sense to change roles like that. The `Switch` classes are the ones that encapsulate the `Implementation` classes.